# Relatively deep nested component to render child which covers whole page

Tags: css, reactjs

I would need to one of my component (which is relatively deep nested) to render component which would cover whole webpage. The thing is that if I would put `position:absolute` in mentioned child component it will be relative to some of its ancestors but not to body. What would be a way for me to achieve expected result? Thanks for all suggestions.

Comment: Have you tried using a portal?

Comment: That's the first time I hear about it. Any more info?

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Comment: css position: fixed can also do it